# Android / eclipse: Can a layout content be scaled to the screen size?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am discovering android programming, I created a simple layer and I'm drawing some sprites like that:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(xPos, yPos);
canvas.drawBitmap(mysprite, matrix, null);
```

But depending on the screen size, everything is not scaled like it would.
Must I scale myself using the screen demensions or is there a parameter for doing that automaticaly.

Thanks

Comment: If you planning on creating a game, I'd recommend you to use AndEngine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way of automatically scaling your sprites, the closest you can get is `dp`, which firstly I don't know if it is possible to size things using `dp` in a game engine, and secondly it is not the best way (because I have found that it simply doesnt change enough) to support multiple screen sizes.

This would be a good place to start however, as it covers different easy(ish) methods to support multiple screen sizes - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html